# HTML Basic - Validation

Tags: html

I know this is a really basic question...

Are these the same for close -

```
 <iframe src="includes/captcha/captcha.php"></iframe>
 <iframe src="includes/captcha/captcha.php"/>
```

And

```
 <div id="container_join_messages" class="shadow"></div>
 <div id="container_join_messages" class="shadow"/>
```

Just wanting to see if I can drop the extra tag at the end and still validate.

Using this doc type

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893193/are-xhtml-self-closing-elements-still-valid-in-html5

Comment: Validate? Yes. Work in browsers as text/html? No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [What are all the valid self-closing elements in XHTML (as implemented by the major browsers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-br) XHTML capable browsers support self-closing on every element.  I've never tried validating such a document myself though.